# Error in SQL - Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote a query to get the amount of prints of a printer each day, but I get the error 1241: Operand should contain 1 column. I already searched and found some answers here, but it didn`t help.

This is my code:

```
select 
            (select insertDate,snmpValue,Hostname 
            from TBL_counterHistory 
            inner join TBL_printer 
            on TBL_counterHistory.fk_tbl_printer  = TBL_printer.pk_id  
            where Hostname = 'ASEPT-OP' 
            and date(insertDate) = date(date_sub(now(),interval 0 day))) 
            - 
            (select insertDate,snmpValue,Hostname 
            from TBL_counterHistory 
            inner join TBL_printer 
            on TBL_counterHistory.fk_tbl_printer  = TBL_printer.pk_id  
            where Hostname = 'ASEPT-OP' 
            and date(insertDate) = date(date_sub(now(),interval 1 day))) 
from dual;
```

I don`t know, what is wrong :(

Comment: The sub-selects may only return one row and column when `-`.

Comment: Substraction operator(-) takes two numbers to operate but your subqueries contain more. Also this is a very different way to achieve what you want. Search the use of group by and sum.

Comment: from dual? you are sure that yoi using mysql?

Comment: why not just select fk_tbl_printer, insertDate, count(*) from TBL_counterHistory group by fk_tbl_printer, insertDate

Comment: Thank you Doruk, it was easier as i thought.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell exactly from your query the exact schema, but this looks overly complex.  Shouldn't it be more like:

```
select count(hist.*) as prints
from TBL_counterHistory hist
inner join TBL_printer prn
on hist.fk_tbl_printer = prn.pk_id
where prn.Hostname ='ASEPT-OP' and
hist.insertDate >= date_sub(now(), interval 1 day) and
hist.insertDate <= now()
```

(Obviously adjusting for date clipping with the date() function as you did as needed).

I don't see the need for all the subselects, especially when you only care about the integer data.  Plus this is just one query instead of two.  Plus you can only do math on single-column subselects anyway (the logic op is friendlier here).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that, you are using Oracle database (because, you have used dual table in your question).

Then, probably you can look for analytical function like **[LAG](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions)**

```
select insertDate, SUM(snmpValue) - LAG(SUM(snmpValue), 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY insertDate), Hostname 
            from TBL_counterHistory 
            inner join TBL_printer 
            on TBL_counterHistory.fk_tbl_printer  = TBL_printer.pk_id  
            where Hostname = 'ASEPT-OP' GROUP BY insertDate,Hostname;
```

**Please note :** I have not tried this.

Comment: This shows me the whole amount of prints, for example two days ago it was 5050, yesterday there were 5100, today 5120 etc. But i wanted to get the subtraction. In this example it is 50 and 20.

Answer (score 0):

By the script you have provided I am assuming that your database schema looks similiar to this one:

[image: Database schema]

Result of your sub-selects look like this:

```
+------------+-----------+----------+
| insertDate | snmpValue | Hostname |
+------------+-----------+----------+
| 2016-09-02 |      5312 | ASEPT-OP |
+------------+-----------+----------+
```

Problem is that you are trying to substract multiple columns - that's what the error says. You should select only one column in your sub-select - the one containing print count.

Your SQL query can be corrected like this:

```
select 
            (select snmpValue 
            from TBL_counterHistory 
            inner join TBL_printer 
            on TBL_counterHistory.fk_tbl_printer  = TBL_printer.pk_id  
            where Hostname = 'ASEPT-OP' 
            and date(insertDate) = date(date_sub(now(),interval 0 day))) 
            - 
            (select snmpValue
            from TBL_counterHistory 
            inner join TBL_printer 
            on TBL_counterHistory.fk_tbl_printer  = TBL_printer.pk_id  
            where Hostname = 'ASEPT-OP' 
            and date(insertDate) = date(date_sub(now(),interval 1 day))) 
from dual;
```